# Error:Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

```
int findNumber(char *exp,int i,int *num)    
{    
    int k=i;    
    char *p;    
    p=exp[i]; //<-- here
    while(*p>='0'&&*p<='9')    
    {
        (*num)=(*num)*10+(*p);
        k++;
        p++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

i keep getting that error in line: (p=exp[i];)
Im trying to send a char array, and (i,num) integers,
the 'i' im just putting it to be 0 for now, until the code works so dont give attention to it. but the function should return the place of the first character in "exp" that is not a number, with being sure that all the ones before are numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p` is a `char*` so you need to assign a pointer to it but `exp[i]` returns a single `char` element from an array.  Try

```
p = &exp[i];
```

or

```
p = (exp + i);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

do correct the line to correspond to the following `p=&(exp[i]);` this means that you are assigning the pointer of exp[i] to p.

Answer (score 0):

You need take the address-of instead of and then pass to `p`, that's a pointer. In other words,you are assign  `char` to a `char* returned from value at`i`index in`exp` array.

Try this: `p = &exp[i];`